# how to scroll horizontally with mouse wheel in emacs when "truncate long lines" is enabled?

Tags: emacs, scroll, mousewheel

In the truncate mode, only partial lines are displayed in the window. I know `C-x <` and `C-x >` can scroll left and right, but I'd like a more convenient way to handle horizontal scrolling - the way alike what we scroll vertically with mouse wheel (possibly combined with pressing other modification keys). Is there any way to set it up in `.emacs`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mwheel-scroll internally calls

(funcall mwheel-scroll-down-function)

resp. for up

a toggle-command might replace this function with scroll-left resp. the other spot with ...-right.

Comment: (setq mwheel-scroll-down-function 'scroll-left)